# Cannot view certain videos in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, video, video-playback

I am having a curious problem while trying to watch videos, both online and locally. Some videos (notably mp4 videos) don't display the video, showing a blank white screen instead, while the audio plays fine.

Some examples:

Chrome (with extensions AdBlock Plus, Ghostery, Chrono Download Manager, Cache Killer, Tampermonkey, and Deluminate; no change when all extensions are disables):

[image: Chome]

VLC:

[image: VLC]

Firefox (which I just installed to see if the issue was happening on it, too):

[image: Firefox]

I've tried all the usual solutions (update graphics drivers, Flash, Firefox, VLC, and Windows), but nothing seems to fix it.

System information:

[image: system]

[image: graphics]

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain their downvote? I can add any additional information that is needed.

Comment: down votes are just opinions